Salesforce CPQ Price Rule keeps on reverting value edited on quote line field
We currently have a price rule that sets a value in the quote line whenever a certain record type is used for a quote, however when we try to change the value of the field the it keeps getting reassigned to the one in the price rule
price rule specs:
Eval Scope: Calculator
Calculation Evaluation Event: On Calculate
Configurator Eval Event: null
we have tried changing the rule, but it keeps getting enforced whenever the field is edited in the editor, any recommendations where it would assign the fields upon adding the product but still be able to edit the mentioned field without it reverting to the one on the price rule

you need another price rule if you Want to edit the value set by PriceRule On QLE.

so this rules Evl Event is After Calculate ,
so this rule set , if quotes record type is this then set the QLE file to Null

I have also faced this issue. please let me know if you need any further info.
Thank You
